# Laplace Equation PDE question confusion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

[image]

This question is confusing me because there are 2 sets of boundary conditions. I don't understand if I'm supposed to solve for $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ or $v_{xx} +v_{yy} = 0$. From the question, it seems like it's the latter. But why are the $u$ boundary conditions there? Do I use them at all? And why are they different to the $v$ boundary conditions? I know how to solve Laplace Equations but this one seems a little strange.

In the beginning, am I supposed to try $v(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ or $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$?

Comment: The question is asking you to solve the equation in $u$ with boundary conditions in $u$ (i.e $u(0,y) = u(x,0) = 0$, $u(1,y) = u(x,1) = 1$). It wants you to do this by _first solving the problem in $v$_, which has one more zero boundary condition than the $u$ problem, then use your solution in $v$ to determine $u$ using the extra BC (which is the last dot point).

Comment: So would treating this simply like I'm solving a laplace equation for $v$, with the $v$ initial conditions only, be good enough?

Comment: Ohh my bad. I just found out that the u conditions were required for a question following this one. Sorry for wasting your time. I'm going to delete this question

Comment: I don't think I am able to anymore. Anyway, I'll flag it and hopefully a mod deletes it